# Объясните, почему код работает именно так?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Простая учебная задача, вывести индекс, если в строке есть буква 'f'. Если буквы 'f' нет, выводим пустоту. Но я не понимаю, почему вместо положенной ему пустоты при вводе строки без буквы 'f' выводит 0. Объясните, плиз, почему так происходит.

```
s = str(input())
if s.find('f') == -1:
    print(s.find(''))
elif s.find('f') == s.rfind('f'):
    print(s.find('f'))
elif s.find('f') != s.rfind('f'):
    print(s.find('f'), s.rfind('f'))
```

Comment: `.find('')` будет всегда возвращать ноль, потому что любая строка начинается с такой последовательности символов. Если хотите вывести пустоту, то так и пишите `print('')`

Comment: В принте функция которые возвращают индексы. Собственно их Вы и видите.

Comment: при чем тут вообще PyCharm l o l

Comment: вам бы пока в idle посидеть с месяцок думаю, pycharm вреден для мозга новичков

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Питон очень симпатичный язык Гвидо ван Россум постарался, он позволяет делать многие вещи проще, с другой стороны почти в каждом языке можно сделать проще, не стоит себя запутывать количесвом строк кода.

```
s = str(input())
result = s.find('f');
print (result if result != -1 else '')
```

тут и строк поменьше, и вызов функции 1 раз, и работает как часы)